# How to control console text color when running npm test?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run tests (using Jest if that matters) by running `npm test` in a Node console, my console text becomes muted green, which is hard for me to read.  I know that I can reset it by running `color` afterward, but what I want to do is be able to control the color so that the output text for each of my tests and their results are in a bright color (configurable by me) instead of a muted color, and I want my original color (bright green) to be restored afterward.

I've tried running `npm test --color always` which has some nice effects, but it doesn't do what I want.  What I'd really like is for the results to be output in bright green (my current default, set in the cmd.exe properties), with the failures, etc. in the red they currently show up in without me having to reset the color (and thereby losing all coloration completely, it all becomes bright green, so it's harder to see failures).

```
Platform:  Win 7 64 bit
Node version: 8.9.3
NPM version: 5.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in way to do this. You would have to just fork the project and then npm install your fork instead of the node module. If you want to remove the colors, you used to be able to do this:

`jest --no-colors`

Not sure if that will help the legibility however.